# After correcting the book with $300$ pages, it was noticed that book contains $1100$ errors.

Tags: probability

After correcting the book with $300$ pages, it was noticed that book contains $1100$ errors. Count the probability of each page containing more than $3$ errors. What is the most likely number of errors on each page?

I'm having trouble with interpretation of this problem. Should the random variable $X$ here be "the number of errors on each page" or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it a Poisson distribution on each page with average $\frac {1100}{300}$ using the logic that each page has a lot of characters on it and each one has a small chance to be wrong.

Comment: Or maybe the book was written by an author with failing eye-sight, and made all the errors on the last 3 pages. Or maybe the author was tired on one night, and made all the errors on Chapter 8. Or maybe the errors are mathematical errors, and the math formulae are only located in the appendix. Or maybe the errors are Uniformly distributed with time. Or maybe they are not.

Comment: @wolfies:  of course those are all possibilities, but we are clearly expected to assume uniformity in some way.  This was my guess for a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Strictly speaking the number of errors on each page is binomial with $n=1100$ and $p=1/300$.